# СПП сравнительно-объектное?

Tags: спп, синтаксический-разбор

С землей давно уже люди обращались отвратительно, будто не даровалась она Создателем как награда для жизни и свершения на ней добрых дел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да. Здесь СПП с придаточным сравнительным.